# How can I pass a list to another window and bind to combobox?

Tags: c#, list, button, combobox, binding

I am trying to do something simple here. I just want to pass selected items from a listview as a list to another window so I can bind it to combobox. Below is the code for my button that generates the list.

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    Attendees = new List<Person>();
    foreach (Person attendee in lvUsers.SelectedItems)
    {
      Attendees.Add(attendee);
    }
    this.Close();
  }
```

How do I pass this list to another window and bind it please?

Comment: Create a public method in the window you want to pass it to that accepts a list as an input, and binds it.
Call that method from the window with the button... I think?

Comment: wpf? winforms? pls tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easy enough to do I just didn't have experience at the time. what I should have done is declared a public list and referenced it from another page. Or create a user control where I can change the datacontext so it can be binded.

Answer (score 0):

snap Attendees list as filed in your window like

```
private List<Attendee> Attendees;
```

then on button click assign it and when you displaying new window of other form pass to constructor like

```
From1 myForm = new Form1(Attendees);
```

Comment: Nice, but what if the window you want to pass the data to is already open?

Comment: then you need public static method in that form where you selecting those values to access some static list

Comment: Static content is here the wrong way at all. Dependency Injection would help (DI is not limited to injection through constructor)

Comment: DI in this case is overkill